# Minecraft Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive, Unable to Play Single Player?

Tags: minecraft

I host a personal server running mostly the same mods. The exception is a few Just Enough _____ mods for different mod packs. The game loads up and even plays in the server I host but I cannot run a single player world without this error. I tried making sense of the code, but to be honest, I cant read java. I know very very little. So its all gobbly gook to me. Anyone make sense of the crash report?

```html
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----

WARNING: coremods are present:
  MicdoodlePlugin (MicdoodleCore-1.12.2.jar)
  Plugin (NotEnoughIDs-1.5.4.4.jar)
  IELoadingPlugin (ImmersiveEngineering-core-0.12-89.jar)
  llibrary (llibrary-core-1.0.10-1.12.2.jar)
  PhosphorFMLLoadingPlugin (phosphor-1.12.2-0.2.4+build46.jar)
  ForgelinPlugin (Shadowfacts-Forgelin-1.12.2.jar)
  TheBetweenlandsLoadingPlugin (TheBetweenlands-3.4.7-core.jar)
  HCASM (HammerCore-1.12.2-2.0.4.9.jar)
Contact their authors BEFORE contacting forge

// Uh... Did I do that?

Time: 12/19/19 11:48 PM
Description: Exception preparing structure feature

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
 at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
 at net.minecraft.world.gen.structure.MapGenVillage.func_75047_a(SourceFile:64)
 at net.minecraft.world.gen.structure.MapGenStructure.func_180701_a(MapGenStructure.java:38)
 at net.minecraft.world.gen.MapGenBase.func_186125_a(SourceFile:34)
 at net.minecraft.world.gen.ChunkGeneratorOverworld.func_185932_a(ChunkGeneratorOverworld.java:228)
 at net.minecraft.world.gen.ChunkProviderServer.func_186025_d(ChunkProviderServer.java:143)
 at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72964_e(World.java:310)
 at net.minecraft.world.World.func_175726_f(World.java:305)
 at net.minecraft.world.World.func_180495_p(World.java:911)
 at net.minecraft.world.World.func_175623_d(World.java:230)
 at net.minecraft.world.World.func_184141_c(World.java:210)
 at net.minecraft.world.WorldProvider.func_76566_a(WorldProvider.java:76)
 at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_73052_b(WorldServer.java:944)
 at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_72963_a(WorldServer.java:866)
 at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.func_71247_a(IntegratedServer.java:97)
 at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.func_71197_b(IntegratedServer.java:209)
 at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:486)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Server thread
Stacktrace:
 at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
 at net.minecraft.world.gen.structure.MapGenVillage.func_75047_a(SourceFile:64)

-- Feature being prepared --
Details:
 Is feature chunk: ~~ERROR~~ IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
 Chunk location: 6,7
 Chunk pos hash: 30064771078
 Structure type: net.minecraft.world.gen.structure.MapGenVillage
Stacktrace:
 at net.minecraft.world.gen.structure.MapGenStructure.func_180701_a(MapGenStructure.java:38)
 at net.minecraft.world.gen.MapGenBase.func_186125_a(SourceFile:34)
 at net.minecraft.world.gen.ChunkGeneratorOverworld.func_185932_a(ChunkGeneratorOverworld.java:228)

-- Chunk to be generated --
Details:
 Location: 14,15
 Position hash: 64424509454
 Generator: net.minecraft.world.gen.ChunkGeneratorOverworld@57a3d869
Stacktrace:
 at net.minecraft.world.gen.ChunkProviderServer.func_186025_d(ChunkProviderServer.java:143)
 at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72964_e(World.java:310)
 at net.minecraft.world.World.func_175726_f(World.java:305)
 at net.minecraft.world.World.func_180495_p(World.java:911)
 at net.minecraft.world.World.func_175623_d(World.java:230)
 at net.minecraft.world.World.func_184141_c(World.java:210)
 at net.minecraft.world.WorldProvider.func_76566_a(WorldProvider.java:76)
 at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_73052_b(WorldServer.java:944)

-- Affected level --
Details:
 Level name: New World
 All players: 0 total; []
 Chunk stats: ServerChunkCache: 0 Drop: 0
 Level seed: 4524058762939609246
 Level generator: ID 00 - default, ver 1. Features enabled: true
 Level generator options: 
 Level spawn location: World: (0,0,0), Chunk: (at 0,0,0 in 0,0; contains blocks 0,0,0 to 15,255,15), Region: (0,0; contains chunks 0,0 to 31,31, blocks 0,0,0 to 511,255,511)
 Level time: 0 game time, 0 day time
 Level dimension: 0
 Level storage version: 0x04ABD - Anvil
 Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
 Level game mode: Game mode: survival (ID 0). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
Stacktrace:
 at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_72963_a(WorldServer.java:866)
 at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.func_71247_a(IntegratedServer.java:97)
 at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.func_71197_b(IntegratedServer.java:209)
 at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:486)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

-- System Details --
Details:
 Minecraft Version: 1.12.2
 Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
 Java Version: 1.8.0_51, Oracle Corporation
 Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
 Memory: 3261047544 bytes (3109 MB) / 8959033344 bytes (8544 MB) up to 19327352832 bytes (18432 MB)
 JVM Flags: 8 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx18G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
 IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 15, tallocated: 95
 FML: MCP 9.42 Powered by Forge 14.23.5.2847 Optifine OptiFine_1.12.2_HD_U_E3 93 mods loaded, 93 mods active
 States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored

 | State  | ID                   | Version              | Source                                         | Signature                                |
 |:------ |:-------------------- |:-------------------- |:---------------------------------------------- |:---------------------------------------- |
 | LCHIJA | minecraft            | 1.12.2               | minecraft.jar                                  | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | mcp                  | 9.42                 | minecraft.jar                                  | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | FML                  | 8.0.99.99            | forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2847.jar                  | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | forge                | 14.23.5.2847         | forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2847.jar                  | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | micdoodlecore        |                      | minecraft.jar                                  | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | movillages           | 1.5.4                | [1.12]MoVillages-1.5.4.jar                     | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | advanced-fishing     | 1.2.0                | Advanced-Fishing-Mod-1.12.2.jar                | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | orbis-lib            | 0.2.0                | orbis-lib-1.12.2-0.2.0+build74.jar             | db341c083b1b8ce9160a769b569ef6737b3f4cdf |
 | LCHIJA | aether               | 0.2.1                | Aether-2-Mod-1.12.2.jar                        | db341c083b1b8ce9160a769b569ef6737b3f4cdf |
 | LCHIJA | architecturecraft    | @VERSION@            | ArchitectureCraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar               | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | baubles              | 1.5.2                | Baubles-Mod-1.12.2.jar                         | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | betterthanllamas     | 1.12.1-1.0.0         | Better-Than-Llamas-Mod-1.12.2.jar              | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | bibliocraft          | 2.4.5                | BiblioCraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar                     | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | bookshelf            | 2.3.577              | Bookshelf-1.12.2-2.3.577.jar                   | d476d1b22b218a10d845928d1665d45fce301b27 |
 | LCHIJA | buildcraftlib        | 7.99.24.1            | BuildCraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | buildcraftcore       | 7.99.24.1            | BuildCraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | buildcraftbuilders   | 7.99.24.1            | BuildCraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | buildcrafttransport  | 7.99.24.1            | BuildCraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | buildcraftsilicon    | 7.99.24.1            | BuildCraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | buildcraftcompat     | 7.99.24.1            | BuildCraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | buildcraftenergy     | 7.99.24.1            | BuildCraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | buildcraftfactory    | 7.99.24.1            | BuildCraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | buildcraftrobotics   | 7.99.24.1            | BuildCraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | casinocraft          | v06                  | CasinoCraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar                     | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | chesttransporter     | 2.8.8                | Chest-Transporter-Mod-1.12.2.jar               | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | coralreef            | 2.0                  | CoralReef-Mod-1.12.2.jar                       | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | dmonsters            | 1.7                  | Deadly-Monsters-Mod-1.12.2.jar                 | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | ptrmodellib          | 1.0.2                | PTRLib-1.12.2.jar                              | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | props                | 2.6.1                | DecoCraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar                       | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | economy              | 1.5                  | Economy-Inc-Mod-1.12.2.jar                     | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | energyconverters     | 1.3.0.15             | energyconverters_1.12.2-1.3.0.15.jar           | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | equivalentstone      | 1.0.0                | Equivalent-Stone-Mod-1.12.2.jar                | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | exoticbirds          | 1.0                  | Exotic-Birds-Mod-1.12.2.jar                    | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | hammercore           | 2.0.4.9              | HammerCore-1.12.2-2.0.4.9.jar                  | 4d7b29cd19124e986da685107d16ce4b49bc0a97 |
 | LCHIJA | jei                  | 4.14.4.264           | JEI-1.12.jar                                   | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | projecte             | 1.12.2-PE1.4.0       | ProjectE-Mod-1.12.2.jar                        | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | expequiv             | 13r                  | ExpandedEquivalence-1.12.2-13r.jar             | 4d7b29cd19124e986da685107d16ce4b49bc0a97 |
 | LCHIJA | golems               | 7.1.7                | Extra-Golems-Mod-1.12.2.jar                    | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | extrautils2          | 1.0                  | Extra-Utilities-Mod-1.12.2.jar                 | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | fairylights          | 2.1.9                | Fairy-Lights-Mod-1.12.2.jar                    | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | mod_lavacow          | 1.0.3                | Fishs-Undead-Rising-Mod-1.12.2.jar             | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | flansmod             | 5.5.2                | Flan's Mod-1.12.2-5.5.2.jar                    | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | flansmodapocalypse   | 1.0                  | Flan's Mod-1.12.2-5.5.2.jar                    | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | foamflower           | 1.12.2-1.0.0.0-beta1 | foamflower-1.12.2-1.0.0.0-beta1.jar            | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | foodexpansion        | 1.3                  | Food-Expansion-Mod-1.12.2.jar                  | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | llibrary             | 1.7.17               | llibrary-1.7.17-1.12.2.jar                     | b9f30a813bee3b9dd5652c460310cfcd54f6b7ec |
 | LCHIJA | fossil               | 8.0.0                | Fossils-and-Archeology-Revival-Mod-1.12.2.jar  | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | freetrading          | 0.2.2                | Freetrading-Mod-1.12.2.jar                     | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | furenikusroads       | 1.0.3                | Furenikus-Roads-Mod-1.12.2.jar                 | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | ic2                  | 2.8.100-ex112        | Industrial-Craft-2-Mod-Experimental-1.12.2.jar | de041f9f6187debbc77034a344134053277aa3b0 |
 | LCHIJA | galacticraftcore     | 4.0.2.220            | Galacticraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar                    | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | galacticraftplanets  | 4.0.2.220            | Galacticraft-Planets-Mod-1.12.2.jar            | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | gbook                | 1.7.2                | Guidebook-1.12.jar                             | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | iceandfire           | 1.7.0                | Ice-and-Fire-Mod-1.12.2.jar                    | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | immersiveengineering | 0.12-89              | Immersive-Engineering-Mod-1.12.2.jar           | 4cb49fcde3b43048c9889e0a3d083225da926334 |
 | LCHIJA | immersivepetroleum   | 1.1.9                | Immersive-Petroleum-Mod-1.12.2.jar             | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | immersivetech        | 1.3.10               | Immersive-Tech-Mod-1.12.2.jar                  | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | industrialrenewal    | 0.6.0                | Industrial-Renewal-Mod-1.12.2.jar              | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | justenoughpetroleum  | 0.1                  | Just-Enough-Petroleum-Mod-1.12.2.jar           | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | mystic               | 0.7.0                | Kether-Mod-1.12.2.jar                          | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | longerdays           | 1.0.4                | Longer-Days-Mod-1.12.2.jar                     | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | lsc                  | 0.6.2.2-alpha        | Loot-Slash-Conquer-Mod-1.12.2.jar              | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | los                  | 1.0.0                | Lots-of-Stuff-Mod-1.12.2.jar                   | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | thaumcraft           | 6.1.BETA26           | Thaumcraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | lycanitesmobs        | 2.0.0.8 - MC 1.12.2  | lycanitesmobs-1.12.2-2.0.0.8.jar               | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | millenaire           | Millénaire 7.1.2     | millenaire-7.1.2.jar                           | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | minejurassic         | 1.0.1                | MineJurassic-Mod-1.12.2.jar                    | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | mocreatures          | 12.0.5               | Mo-Creatures-Mod-1.12.2.jar                    | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | cdm                  | 0.4.1                | MrCrayfishs-Device-Mod-1.12.2.jar              | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | cfm                  | 6.2.0                | MrCrayfishs-Furniture-Mod-1.12.2.jar           | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | mutantmobs           | 1.0.1                | Mutant-Mobs-Mod-1.12.2.jar                     | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | neid                 | 1.5.4.4              | NotEnoughIDs-1.5.4.4.jar                       | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | openablewindows      | 0.0.1                | Openable-Windows-Mod-1.12.2.jar                | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | ordinarycoins        | 1.3.2                | Ordinary-Coins-Mod-1.12.2.jar                  | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | pa                   | 1.12.2               | Passive-Aggression-Mod-1.12.2.jar              | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | pixelmon             | 6.3.4                | Pixelmon-1.12.2-6.3.4-universal.jar            | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | poweradapters        | 1.0.9                | PowerAdapters-1.12.2-1.0.9.jar                 | d476d1b22b218a10d845928d1665d45fce301b27 |
 | LCHIJA | df-roads             | 1.4-mc1.12.2         | Realistic-Road-Mod-1.12.2.jar                  | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | srparasites          | 1.1                  | Scape-and-Run-Parasites-Mod-1.12.2.jar         | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | forgelin             | 1.8.3                | Shadowfacts-Forgelin-1.12.2.jar                | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | parry                | 1.0                  | Shield-Parry-Mod-1.12.2.jar                    | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | modname              | 1.0.2                | Subnauticraft-Mod-1.12.2.jar                   | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | swanboat             | 1.12.2-1.0.0         | Swan-Boats-Mod-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | thaumicjei           | 1.6.0                | Thaumic-JEI-Mod-1.12.2 (1).jar                 | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | thaumicrestoration   | 1.3.1                | Thaumic-Restoration-Mod-1.12.2.jar             | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | bspkrscore           | at_0.9               | TreeCapitator-Mod-1.12.jar                     | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | treecapitator        | at_0.9               | TreeCapitator-Mod-1.12.jar                     | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | vending              | 1.12.2-3.0.1.2       | Vending-Block-Mod-1.12.2.jar                   | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | thejungle            | 1.1024.1222          | Welcome-to-the-Jungle-Mod-1.12.2.jar           | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | zoocraftdiscoveries  | 1.0                  | Zoocraft-Discoveries-Mod-1.12.2.jar            | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | phosphor-lighting    | 1.12.2-0.2.4         | phosphor-1.12.2-0.2.4+build46.jar              | f0387d288626cc2d937daa504e74af570c52a2f1 |
 | LCHIJA | jurassicraft         | 2.1.18               | JurassiCraft-1.12.2-2.1.18.jar                 | None                                     |
 | LCHIJA | thebetweenlands      | 3.4.7                | TheBetweenlands-3.4.7-universal.jar            | 38067d6878811efb38b6a045521cfd80b9b60b38 |

 Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
MicdoodlePlugin (MicdoodleCore-1.12.2.jar)
  micdoodle8.mods.miccore.MicdoodleTransformer
Plugin (NotEnoughIDs-1.5.4.4.jar)
  ru.fewizz.neid.asm.Transformer
IELoadingPlugin (ImmersiveEngineering-core-0.12-89.jar)
  blusunrize.immersiveengineering.common.asm.IEClassTransformer
llibrary (llibrary-core-1.0.10-1.12.2.jar)
  net.ilexiconn.llibrary.server.core.plugin.LLibraryTransformer
  net.ilexiconn.llibrary.server.core.patcher.LLibraryRuntimePatcher
PhosphorFMLLoadingPlugin (phosphor-1.12.2-0.2.4+build46.jar)
  
ForgelinPlugin (Shadowfacts-Forgelin-1.12.2.jar)
  
TheBetweenlandsLoadingPlugin (TheBetweenlands-3.4.7-core.jar)
  thebetweenlands.core.TheBetweenlandsClassTransformer
HCASM (HammerCore-1.12.2-2.0.4.9.jar)
  com.zeitheron.hammercore.asm.HammerCoreTransformer
 GL info: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
 Hammer Core Information: FluidDictionary Info: Registered 2 fluids.
OreDictionary Info: Registered 809 names; 1582 stacks.
Pastebin Connection: Okay.
Dependent Mods:
    -Expanded Equivalence (expequiv) @13r

 Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
 Player Count: 0 / 8; []
 Type: Integrated Server (map_client.txt)
 Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, It has to do with your mods. It is something about random number generation. Try disabling them one by one.

> ### References:
>
> ['bound must be positive' error.](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/modification-development/2583319-bound-must-be-positive-error)